# Planck's Law in terms of wavelength

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

I am drawing a blank when it comes to equation transformation. Wikipedia [gives two equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Various_forms_of_expression_of_Planck.27s_law) for the spectral radiance of black body:

- First as a function of frequency $\nu$: $$I(\nu, T) = \frac{2 h \nu^3}{c^2}\cdot\frac{1}{e^\frac{h \nu}{k T} - 1}$$
- Then as a function of wavelength $\lambda$ : $$I'(\lambda, T) = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\cdot\frac{1}{e^\frac{h c}{\lambda k T}-1}$$

And I don't see how they get $\lambda^5$ term. I'm assuming that the transformation is just $\nu \rightarrow c/\lambda$, but that gives
$$
\frac{2 h \nu^3}{c^2} \Rightarrow \frac{2 hc}{\lambda^3} \neq \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}
$$

Similar transformation happens at other parts in the article also. I'm obviously missing something, likely completely trivial.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Expanding on Ron's comment:

$$I(\nu ,T)d\nu =\frac{2h\nu ^3}{c^2}\frac{d\nu }{e^{\frac{h\nu }{kT}}-1}$$
$$\nu \to \frac{c}{\lambda },\quad d\nu \to c\frac{d\lambda }{\lambda ^2}$$
$$I(\lambda ,T)d\lambda =\frac{2h}{c^2}\left(\frac{c}{\lambda }\right)^3\frac{1}{e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}-1}c\frac{d\lambda }{\lambda ^2}=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda ^5}\frac{d\lambda }{e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}-1}$$

Comment: Why can't you just use $\nu \to \frac{c}{\lambda }$ to change variables?  Neither $d \lambda$ or $d \nu$ appear in the equations of the original question, so why is it necessary to calculate $\frac{d \nu}{d \lambda }$ at all?

Comment: @iwantmyphd because $I(\nu, T) d\nu = I(\lambda, T) d\lambda$