# Non-invariance of density extrema with re-parameterization

Tags: density

Consider a density function $f(x)$, in one dimension for simplicity. Assume that it has an extremum at $x^*$, so that $f'(x^*) = 0$.

If I make a change of variables via $x = x(\xi)$, then I must consider the transformed density:

$$g(\xi) = f(x(\xi))\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\xi}$$

For simplicity I will assume that $x(\xi)$ is a monotonous increasing function.

It is somewhat unintuitive to me that the extremum of $g(\xi)$ is *not* (in general) at the same spot, i.e., that if $x^* = x(\xi^*)$, then $\xi^*$ is not, in general, an extremum  of $g(\xi)$. Mathematically the reason is simple:

$$g'(\xi) = f'(x(\xi))\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\xi}\right)^2 + f(x(\xi))\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm d\xi^2}$$

Although the first term vanishes at $\xi^*$, the second term need not vanish there.

I find this very unintuitive. It implies that the "density extrema" have no physical meaning, because they depend on the parameterization used to describe the density. However, if $f^*=f(x^*) = 0$, then this location is invariant. That is, extrema that are zero *are* invariant.

I am looking for examples that make this fact more obvious. Maybe there is a different way to look at it that renders the non-invariance evident? Is there a physical situation where this absence of invariance becomes obvious?

Comment: possible duplicate: [The strange thing about the maximum in Planck's law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91192/84967) and links therein.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks. I was just thinking of Plack's law. The answer there is very thorough. However, can we not mark this as a duplicate and see if there are any more examples? I would be interested in other physical instances of the same mathematical phenomenon.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform For example, I was also thinking of fluid dynamics. As the fluid moves, the coordinates of the "particles" at time $t$ can be thought of as a change of variables of the coordinates at time $0$. If the density maximum changes place in ordinary Cartesian variables, I think this could be another example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. It is just an example where the maximum moves. Consider $f(x) = 1 - (x-1)^2$ and $x(\xi) = \mathrm e^\xi$.

The original function has a maximum at $x^*=1$:

[image]

After the re-parameterization, the location of the maximum moves to $\xi = \ln(4/3) \approx 0.288$, which corresponds to $x = 4/3 \approx 1.333$.

[image]