# Planck's law question

Tags: computational-physics, differentiation, thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

I was reading Wikipedia article about [Planck's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) and I wanted to make the same graph as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#/media/File:Black_body.svg).
I took this equation
$$ B(\nu,T)=\frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}}-1}$$

but I got different graphs. Maximum is shifted. For example, in Wikipedia maximum for 5000K is around 0.5-0.6$\mu m$, but I got maximum for 5000K at 1$\mu m$. My graph is below:
[image]
I used this Wolfram Mathematic program below to build this graph.

```
kV = 1.380649*10^(-23);
hV = 6.62607015*10^(-34);
cV = 299792458;
f[l_] = cV/l/10^(-6);(*Convert Wave Length to Frequency*)
Bf[f_, T_] = 2*hV*f^3/cV^2*1/(Exp[(hV*f)/(kV*T)] - 1);

Plot[{Bf[f[l], 5000], Bf[f[l], 4000], Bf[f[l], 3000]},
 {l, 0.3, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red},
 PlotLegends -> {"5000K", "4000K", "3000K"},
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

My question is what am I doing wrong and why I am getting a different maximum?

UPDATE 1.

I removed $\mu m$ conversion to have everything in the same SI units.

Graph and program below.
[image]

```
kV = 1.380649*10^(-23);
hV = 6.62607015*10^(-34);
cV = 299792458;
f[l_] = cV/l;
Bf[f_, T_] = 2*hV*f^3/cV^2*1/(Exp[(hV*f)/(kV*T)] - 1)

Plot[{Bf[f[l], 5000], Bf[f[l], 4000], Bf[f[l], 3000]},
 {l, 0.3*10^(-6), 2*10^(-6)},
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Red},
 PlotLegends -> {"5000K", "4000K", "3000K"},
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: I think this is not really the place for this question, but I think you multiply by 10^6 in your f[l] function because you want to get into microns as your length unit, but you don't do the same for your other constants, so there's a unit mismatch. Boltzmann's constant and Planck's constant will be different by some orders of magnitude.

Comment: @flevinBombastus If I remove microns results is the same. See UPDATE 1.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91192/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13611/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing the spectral radiance in frequency $B(f,T)$ with the spectral radiance in wavelength $B(\lambda,T)$. Because these are differential distributions, you cannot simply replace $f=c/\lambda$ to go from one to another. You must take into account the Jacobian of transformation.

$$d\Omega=B(f,T)df = B(\lambda,T)d\lambda$$

$$\begin{align}
\implies B(\lambda,T)&=\overset{\color{red}{[1]}}{-}B(f(\lambda),T)\frac{df}{d\lambda}\\
&=+\frac{c}{\lambda^2}B(f(\lambda),T)\\
&=+\frac{f^2}{c}B(f(\lambda),T)
\end{align}$$

If you change that definition it should work fine.

Edit: The $\color{red}{[1]}$ marker above is in reference to @rob's comment, which is a minus sign I forgot to write. One must take into account limits of integration in the above relation between $B(\lambda,T)$ and $B(f,T)$. If $f_1<f_2$, then $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$, and therefore:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\lambda_2}^{\lambda_1} B(\lambda,T)d\lambda &= \int_{f_1}^{f_2} B(f,T)df\\
&=\int_{\lambda(f_1)=\lambda_1}^{\lambda(f_2)=\lambda_2} B(f(\lambda),T)
\frac{df}{d\lambda}\,d\lambda \\
&=\int_{\lambda_2}^{\lambda_1} -B(f(\lambda),T)
\frac{df}{d\lambda}\,d\lambda \\
&\\
& \implies \boxed{B(\lambda,T)=-B(f(\lambda),T)\frac{df}{d\lambda}}
\end{align} $$

Comment: Because it took me too long to figure it out on my own fifteen years ago, I’ll mention it here: the meaning of the negative sign is *not* that the distribution $B$ goes negative, but that a small increase in frequency $df$ corresponds to a small *decrease* in wavelength $d\lambda$. It’s all about keeping the integral the same, down to the order of the limits of integration.

Comment: Just to add to @rob's comment -- you will find different conventions used often without explanation. To keep the order of the limits of integration the same, indeed you need the minus sign. However, sometimes people implicitly require that the limits of integration are always increasing, even if that means the sense of the measure changes sign, in which case you will see the Jacobian transformation rule written with an absolute value sign. It's just a different convention for the same (subtle!) point.

Comment: @rob I've addressed the concern in my answer with an edit. It was a silly mistake that I didn't even catch!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works fine. I just needed to read half a page more in Wikipedia and there is a proper formula for wave length there $\Large B(\lambda,T)=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kT}}-1}$

Comment: The only question is if Sun is green (500 nm for 5778K) or infrared ($3.4\times10^{14}Hz$ or 883 nm for 5778K) :)

Comment: Actually the answer is clear from here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91192/the-strange-thing-about-the-maximum-in-plancks-law

Comment: @Zlelik the lesson learned here is actually quite valuable. The same logic applies when trying to express any probability/differential density function in one variable (e.g. $\rho(x)$), to the same density function but in another variable (e.g. $\rho (y)$). It's not as simple as saying $\rho(y)=\rho(y(x))$. One must also take into account the integration measure, and region of integration. This shows up in statistics a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Ah you got caught by something subtle! Planck's law gives a probability **density** function in terms of the frequency $B(\nu,T)$. To convert to the probability density function in terms of $\lambda$ (let's call it $\tilde{B}(\lambda,T)$), you can't just set $\nu=c/\lambda$. You need to include a *Jacobian* factor.

In more detail:

What remains invariant under a change in variables is the **probability** $dp=B(\nu,T)d\nu=\tilde{B}(\lambda,T)d\lambda$. As a result...
\begin{equation}
\tilde{B}(\lambda,T) = \left|\frac{d \nu}{d\lambda}\right| B(\nu,T) = \frac{c}{\lambda^2} B\left(\frac{c}{\lambda},T\right)
\end{equation}
I bet if you include the $c/\lambda^2$ factor in your plot, you will get the same result as wikipedia. Let me know how it goes!