# Planck's law: $B_\nu (\nu, T)$ to $B_\lambda (\lambda, T)$

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

Wikipedia says that Planck's law is:

$$B_\nu (\nu, T) = \frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}\times \frac{1}{e^{h\nu /(k_BT)} - 1}$$

So, to convert this to wavelength, I substituted $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ which gave me:

$$B_\lambda(\lambda, T) = \frac{2hc}{\lambda^3}\times \frac{1}{e^{hc/(\lambda k_BT)} - 1}$$

However, Wikipedia says that:

$$B_\lambda(\lambda, T) = \frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\times \frac{1}{e^{hc/(\lambda k_BT)} - 1}$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13611/

Comment: In the link : [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law)  you read the first few lines. Be careful to continue in paragraph "Correspondence between spectral variable forms" :
\begin{equation}
B\left( \lambda,T\right)\mathrm{d}\lambda=-B\left[ \nu( \lambda),T\right]\mathrm{d}\nu 
\tag{01}
\end{equation}