# Planck equation in terms of frequency

Tags: thermal-radiation, frequency, wavelength

Given $$u (\lambda) d\lambda = \frac{8 \pi hc \lambda ^{-5}}{e^{\frac {hc}{\lambda k t}}-1}d\lambda,$$ I want to convert this into frequency form $u(\nu)d \nu$. Basically, I want to covert the amount of energy in a wavelength $\lambda \to \lambda + d\lambda$ to the corresponding expression from $\nu \to \nu + d\nu$. I know that $\nu = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ and to replace this in the denominator, and I know that $d\nu = -\frac{c}{\lambda^2}d\lambda$, but I can't make the formula come out right. What am I missing?

Comment: What did you get? Did you fail on contants or on $d\lambda/\lambda^5 \propto d\nu\nu^3$?

Comment: The latter. Additionally, I'm not sure where the negative sign from the derivative goes.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13611/2451 and links therein.